# Как сделать что бы js заново проверил классы?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы js заново проверил классы . Просто есть два скрипта. Один при клике добавляет класс боди а второй обращается к этому классу. К сожалению второй скрипт не работает, так как при иницеализации данного класса у боди нету? Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Дайте примерный код того что вы хотите сделать?